# How I can transform json to csv with jq?

Tags: json, linux, csv, jq

My json file is similar of this:

```
{
"A1": "1.2"
"A2": "3.5"
"A3": "2.6"
}
```

I need transform it to csv file and it looks like this:

```
A1,1.2
A2,3.5
A3,2.6
```

My code is:

```
jq -r 'map(.[] | tonumber) | @csv' file.json > file.csv
```

and my result is:

```
1.2,3.5,2.6
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fix your example JSON so it's valid:

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, (.value | tonumber)] | @csv' input.json
"A1",1.2
"A2",3.5
"A3",2.6
```

`to_entries` turns an object into an array of objects with the `key` field holding the name of one of the original object's keys and `value` its corresponding value. Then turn each of those objects into a two-element array which is fed to `@csv`.